# Dictionary Many To Many

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, dictionary, ado.net

i need to impliment many to many relation with dictionary and ADO.
Here is my code and i need to make companies on client non-repeatable.It is not allowed to use order by in query. I need some help thanks ! 
Using query :

```
string Query= "SELECT c.ID, c.FirstName, c.LastName,
                      c.EGN, c.Birthday,
                      com.ID as CompanyID,
                      com.Name,
                      com.Location
                FROM Clients c 
                LEFT JOIN ClientCompanies cc 
                ON  c.ID=cc.ClientID 
                LEFT JOIN Company com ON cc.CompanyID=com.ID";



       static List<Client> GetClients(SqlCommand command)
    {
        List<Client> listClients = new List<Client>();
        Dictionary<int, Client> dicClients = new Dictionary<int, Client>();
        Dictionary<int, Company> dicCompanies = new Dictionary<int, Company>();
        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Client newClient = null;
                Company newCompany = null;
                int clientId = (int)reader["ID"];

                dicClients.TryGetValue(clientId, out newClient);
                if (newClient == null)
                {
                    newClient = new Client();
                    newClient.ID = (int?)reader["ID"];
                    newClient.FirstName = (!reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("FirstName")) ? (string)reader["FirstName"] : null);
                    newClient.LastName = (!reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("LastName")) ? (string)reader["LastName"] : null);
                    newClient.EGN = (!reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("EGN")) ? (string)reader["EGN"] : null);
                    newClient.Birthday = (!reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("Birthday")) ? (string)reader["Birthday"] : null);
                }

                int companyId = (!reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("CompanyID")) ? (int)reader["CompanyID"] : 0);

                //Some check with dictionary

                if (newCompany == null)
                {
                    newCompany = new Company();
                    newCompany.ID = (!reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("CompanyID")) ? (int?)reader["CompanyID"] : null);
                    newCompany.Name = (!reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("Name")) ? (string)reader["Name"] : null);
                    newCompany.Location = (!reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("Name")) ? (string)reader["Name"] : null);
                    newClient.ClientTo.Add(newCompany);
                }

                dicClients[clientId] = newClient;
            }
            listClients = dicClients.Values.ToList();
            return listClients;
        }
```

Comment: What do you need help with? Is it not working as expected, or do you get an error, or what..? Is the problem with the SQL or the code, or both? And why can't ORDER BY be used?

Comment: I have task to make it without order by in query. I mean i have to make this solution as fast is possible for cpu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You ended half way. You still transport all those companies through network, process them and throw them away in the end. To get maximum speed, fetch every item only once. Split that into three selects:

```
SELECT c.ID, c.FirstName, c.LastName, c.EGN, c.Birthday FROM Clients c;
SELECT com.ID as CompanyID, com.Name, com.Location FROM Company com;
SELECT cc.ClientID, cc.CompanyID FROM ClientCompanies cc;
```

to get three data collections

```
Dictionary<int, Client> dicClients
Dictionary<int, Company> dicCompanie
List<Tuple<int, int>> listClientCompanies
```

The rest depends on what You want to do with that, but You have all data available. You may need to add some filtering into those queries if they return data that You do not need (`WHERE EXISTS(...)` or even simple filtering `JOIN` with `ClientCompanies` table or other).